# Facebook ShareDialog always returns .canceled on completion

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Share dialog opens facebook app and despite content is shared successfuly I always receive *.cancelled* callback. In both cases - when I cancel sharing and when sharing is successfull. Any idea what is wrong?
Pods versions:

```
Using Bolts (1.8.4)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.20.2)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.20.2)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.20.2)
Using FacebookCore (0.2.0)
Using FacebookLogin (0.2.0)
Using FacebookShare (0.2.0)
```

Snippet for showing dialog:

```
    @IBAction func onShareClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    do{
        var myContent = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/8MinuteWorkoutChallenge")!)
        myContent.hashtag = Hashtag("#8MWC")

        let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: myContent)
        shareDialog.mode = .native
        shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true
        shareDialog.completion = { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                print("Share succeeded")
            case .failed:
                self.shareButton.isHidden = true
            case .cancelled:
                print("Share cancelled")
            }
        }

        try shareDialog.show()
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

config

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb188***33776</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>18851***3776</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>8MWC</string>
```

Comment: Have you asked for publish permission from user ?

Comment: No, I didn't. There is nothing about that in docs and sharing works, but not the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this below code to show the FB share Dialog to current View controller:

```
{
   let shareDialog: FBSDKShareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    shareDialog.shareContent = content
    shareDialog.delegate = self
    shareDialog.fromViewController = self
    shareDialog.show()
}
```

This works for me to share the link to facebook. You can use delegation method to get the share status call back.

Comment: This is for old sdk. The new one has different api

Comment: shareDialog.presentingViewController = self did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check if permission is granted for `publish action`, if yes, then `share` your `content`.
Otherwise, get a permission from user to publish post on their timeline and then share post if permission is granted.

```
   if FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("publish_actions") {
        if FBSDKShareAPI().self.canShare() {
            FBSDKShareAPI.share(with: videoContent, delegate: self)
        } else {
            print("Graph API can not share your video")
        }

    } else {

        // Get publish_actions permission from fb app and upload photo to share.
        let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(withPublishPermissions: ["publish_actions"], from: fromViewController, handler: { (result, error) in

            if result != nil && error == nil {

                if FBSDKShareAPI().self.canShare() {
                    FBSDKShareAPI.share(with: videoContent, delegate: self)
                } else {
                    print("Graph API can not share your video")
                }
            } else if error != nil {
                print("Error in sharing photo:- \(error!)")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: publish_actions is deperecated now.